# trying to include my images file path with php

Tags: php, html

First off, this is the file structure of my website.

[File Structure Of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH84R.png)

I made a header file called  header.html.php which includes all my code for the header and a img tag to include a company logo

header.html.php:

```
<header class="header_wrapper">
    <img class="logo" src="<?php echo __DIR__ . 'logo.png';?>" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Track Your Shipment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sell Device</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    </header>
```

When I included my header.html.php file into my body.html.php page, my whole header appears except for my logo, the image. Here is the way I included my html files.

body.html.php

```
<!-- connect the header and then the header css file -->
<?php include(__DIR__ . "/../header/header.html.php");?>
<style>
<?php include(__DIR__."/../header/header.css");?>
</style>
```

My issue is right here i believe

```
<img class="logo" src="<?php echo __DIR__ . 'logo.png';?>" alt="logo">
```

But If i just use

```
<img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
```

That wouldn't work either because it is a relative file path.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You need to create a ***URL*** that is relative to your web server's root directory. What you're doing is create an *absolute file path* relative to the hard disk of your computer; which makes little sense now, and will stop making any sense whatsoever once you upload the site to an actual server on the internet.

Comment: @deceze I started to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. So one of my urls is `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dashboard/website/header/header.html.php');` Would this line of code be relative to my web server's root directory?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Root path (absolute path)

```
<img class="logo" src="/header/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

The first `/` means that no matter what path you are in, it will start at the web root of your website.